# Order list of vector by number of occurency in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to order (reverse order) a list of lists by the number of occurrences of a specific element.

I've tried with the subsequent expression:

```
a = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1], [0,1,1]
a.sort(key = (a).count(1) , reverse = True)
```

the desired output must be:

```
a = [[1,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,0]]
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Probably, I'm stretching the definition of "key". Is there a way to do what I'm trying above without hard-coding it and do it in a more pythonic way?

Comment: `(a).count(1)` immediately calls the `count` method on `list`, counting the number of times `1` occurs in `a` and returning that count as an `int`, which will be `0`. What you need to provide to the `key` parameter is a callable, a lambda, for example. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: That's clear now, thank you to all who answered my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` argument works by taking a *callable* and applying it to each element in your list to determine which position it should sit in, in the final sorted result.

In your case, you pass `a.count(1)`, which is evaluated *before* the call to `list.sort` is made. While sorting, python will try to `__call__` the result passed (in this case, `0`), and fails because `int`s are not callable. The trick, as mentioned above, is to pass a callable instead.

If you want to pass an *inline callable*, you will need to use a `lambda` function:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x.count(1), reverse=True)
```

Otherwise, define a function as the other answers show and pass that to `list.sort` as the sorting key.

Finally, if your list only has 0s and 1s, you can micro-optimise by using `key=sum`.

```
a.sort(key=sum, reverse=True)
```

In this instance (assuming this case holds), `sum(x)` and `x.count(1)` would return the *same* result.

Comment: Is this really a micro-optimization? I'd expect `sum` and `count(1)` to be around the same speed, maybe with `sum` starting off faster but falling behind as the lists get huge. And I wouldn't expect the speed gain to be enough to compensate for the brittleness and being less obvious.

Comment: @abarnert Microoptimization = no lambda... it would still be the same complexity, of course.

Comment: Yeah, no lambda means it'll almost surely win for huge _numbers_ of lists, but more work means I'm not sure about huge _lists_. Anyway, if it matters, you'd want to test it on your real data, so no point arguing about our guesses. :)

Comment: @abarnert was actually attempting to do that right now. I don't think partial will work with `list.count`, since value is actually a positional argument.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops, you're right about `list.count`; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `key` parameter accepts a *callable object*, e.g. a *function*. You pass the *result of calling a function* to the argument, which will get evaluated to an `int`.

So, instead, you could do:

```
def count_key(x): return x.count(1)

a = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1], [0,1,1]
a.sort(key=count_key, reverse = True)
```

Your original attempt suggests you were looking for an anonymous function. Python supports anonymous functions with the `lambda` keyword, and this would be a typical use-case:

```
a = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1], [0,1,1]
a.sort(key=lambda x: x.count(1), reverse = True)
```

### Edit to add some tests

Quick tests:

```
In [11]: %%timeit import functools; a = 10000*[100*[0,1,0],100*[1,1,1], 100*[0,1,1]]
    ...: a.sort(key = lambda x: x.count(1), reverse = True)
    ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 54.7 ms per loop

In [12]: %%timeit import functools; a = 10000*[100*[0,1,0],100*[1,1,1], 100*[0,1,1]]
    ...: a.sort(key = sum, reverse = True)
    ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 75.1 ms per loop
```

Surprisingly, `lambda` seems to win out. However, if the inner lists are small, `sum` wins:

```
In [16]: %%timeit import functools; a = 10000*[[0,1,0],[1,1,1], [0,1,1]]
    ...: a.sort(key = lambda x: x.count(1), reverse = True)
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 5.2 ms per loop

In [17]: %%timeit import functools; a = 10000*[[0,1,0],[1,1,1], [0,1,1]]
    ...: a.sort(key = sum, reverse = True)
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 3.82 ms per loop
```

Now, with even bigger inner lists, `lambda` gets the edge again:

```
In [18]: %%timeit import functools; a = 10000*[1000*[0,1,0],1000*[1,1,1], 1000*[0,1,1]]
    ...: a.sort(key = lambda x: x.count(1), reverse = True)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 482 ms per loop

In [19]: %%timeit import functools; a = 10000*[1000*[0,1,0],1000*[1,1,1], 1000*[0,1,1]]
    ...: a.sort(key = sum, reverse = True)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 679 ms per loop
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it will not, the double-percent timeit ipython magic, `%%timeit` will make the first line the `setup` and the second will be the `stmt`

Comment: Okay, one more thing. Did you time this on python3.6? I cannot reproduce your results exactly. I tried two cases as you did, `a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10000, 100)).tolist()` and `a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 10000)).tolist()` and in both cases, `key=sum` won out, but not by much. Another note, I timed with `sorted` instead of `list.sort`.

Answer (score 2):

The `key` needs to be a *function*, not an expression.

You can turn any expression into a function in-line with `lambda`:

```
a.sort(key=lambda sublist: sublist.count(1), reverse=True)
```

Often it's clearer to either put the function out of line:

```
def countones(lst):
    return lst.count(1)

a.sort(key=countones, reverse=True)
```

… or use a (bound or unbound) method, partial, or higher-order function. Something like this:

```
a.sort(key=functools.partial(list.count, value=1), reverse=True)
```

… except that `list.count` is actually a builtin that doesn't take keyword arguments, so you can't write it that simply.

In this case, I think the `lambda` is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using a lambda funcion:

```
>>> a.sort(key = lambda x: sum(x),reverse = True)
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: `key=sum` is enough, `lambda x: sum(x)` does no more than `sum`.

Comment: @timgeb you are right, but this is other way to do it. In fact, in my answer, I had added your comment but I had other comment from another person (with vote negative) because I had repeated the answer you comments, and therfore, I removed it

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
a = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1], [0,1,1]]
print(sorted(a,key=lambda x:x.count(1),reverse=True))
```

output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Whydoyounotlikespaces?Seemsprettycrammed.